# Windows Service, Plugin load trouble

Tags: c#, plugins, windows-services

I have written a plugin system inspired from NotePad.NET, this plugin system read all DLL File in given folder and load them at runtime if they match my Interface using reflection. code is below

```
foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir + "\\plugins\\", "*.dll", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
if (file.EndsWith(".dll"))
{
    Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
    foreach (Type t in dll.GetTypes())
    {
        try
        {
            log.WriteLine("Trying to match " + t.BaseType.FullName + " with " + typeof(Acoustical.PluginBase.FileFormatBase).FullName + " and " + typeof(Acoustical.PluginBase.ReportBase).FullName);
            if (t.BaseType.FullName == typeof(FileFormatBase).FullName)
            {
                log.WriteLine(" we compare for " + t.BaseType.FullName);
                try
                {
                    fileformatPlugin.Add((dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(t));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.WriteLine("Error in loading File Plugin ::" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                }
                continue;
            }
            else if (t.BaseType.FullName == typeof(ReportBase).FullName)
            {
                log.WriteLine(" we compare for " + t.BaseType.FullName);
                reportPlugin.Add((dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(t));
                continue;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            log.WriteLine("Error in loading Plugin ::" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
    dll = null;
}
```

Above code shows the part where Iterate over all found files in folder and than load them.

The above code works for me if I use the Windows Form or WCF interface application, it works on Windows service but doesn't guarantee that. It 60-70% of time on recompile doesn't load the plugin, then I after 10-15 attempts it sometime load plugins or sometime load only 1-2 plugins.

as you see I put Try catch on almost all lines to trace where the error is coming but no error is showing up. Since it is Windows SErvice it is not possible to debug when this code is written on ONStartup event.

I did see "We compare for" line in log, but when we try to see fileformatplugin got any element it's count remain 0 and error line is not there in log.

Any advice?

Comment: Assuming you have the necessary permissions, you can call `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` in the `OnStartup()` callback to debug your service.  When you run it, you'll be presented a dialog to start an instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: That is really helpful, though I solve [maybe], by using strong name, things are better now.